# Have a class always return true for method exists

Tags: php

I have a class that I would like to return true when method_exists() etc is called on it so that I can process it via __call().

I stumbled upon this link that talks about the removal of the behavior and __call()
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=32429

Hopefully that makes sense. Thanks.

This is for a comment that I was not clear enough.

```
class MyClass {
  public function __call($method, $args) {
    if($method === 'something') {
      // do something
    }
  }
}
```

Then somewhere else there is

```
$my_class = new MyClass();
if(method_exists($my_class, 'something')) {
  // do something
  // But does not because method exists returns false
  // I would like it to return true if possible
}
```

Is there something complicated about that I'm not understanding?

Comment: `method_exists()` should return true if a method exists. It doesn't work on classes. Please rephrase your question if you think I misunderstood you.

Comment: "when method_exists() etc" What does that mean? Rewrite your question with more details/examples.

Comment: @Truth: `method_exists` works on classes.

Comment: hmmm... I'm confused.
`method_exists('MyClass', 'my_method');`

Comment: Would `is_callable` work here?  `is_callable(array($my_class, 'something'))` returns `true`.

Comment: That's very interesting. This class won't have much control on how it is used so I feel like the interface would feel inconsistent if someone used method_exists on it and ended up with false. And then is_callable gave true. But that is a very good point. Thank you.

Comment: @Mike: Is there any reason why you want to handle it in `__call` and not just create a method instead?

Comment: @netcoder The current design allows for a potentially infinite number of methods. Today I realized the method_exists would present a misleading interface. I was asking here to make sure before I went about a change in design which appears now to be the proper option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`method_exists` will not detect undefined-methods which the `__call` magic handles, because the undefined method you pass it *actually* does not exist. It would be considered a bug if it did, as linked in your question.

The only way to do this (without a PECL extension like [runkit](http://pecl.php.net/package/runkit) or modifying the PHP source), is to use some namespace *black magic* to override the behavior of `method_exists`:

```
namespace Foo;

function method_exists($object, $method) {
    return \method_exists($object, '__call') ?: 
           \method_exists($object, $method);
}

class Bar {
    public function __call($n, $a) { }
}
class Baz { }

var_dump(method_exists('Foo\Baz', 'hello')); // false
var_dump(method_exists('Foo\Bar', 'hello')); // true
```

I wouldn't recommend it, but hey, you asked for it.

Comment: That was what I had run into as well. Bummer there isn't a way to have a class determine whether something exists as opposed to an outside function. oh well. Thanks.

Comment: I'll mark this as the answer soon. I'm just holding out hope for a little bit just to see if someone has something else. Thanks for the insight, I really appreciate it.